# При нажатие кнопку, отправляется data атрибут в js

Tags: javascript, html, form

Я слаб в js. Помогите с кодом.

При нажатии на `<input type="button" data-atr="123456789" value="Отправить">`

`data-atr` - его значение отправляется в js для переменной `mydata`

Comment: И это не переменная, а имя параметра.

Answer (score 2):

1. В современных браузерах можно так.
2. Я бы всё-таки использовал `type="submit"`.

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.getElementsByName('mydata')[0].value = e.target.dataset.atr
  e.target.form.submit()
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="mydata">
  <input type="button" data-atr="123456789" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле всё можно сделать проще. Кнопка отправляется только если она нажата.

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit" name="mydata" value="123456789">Отправить</button>
  <button type="submit" name="mydata" value="000">Отправить</button>
</form>
```